# Search field in text file

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have some coding which displays a label if the value of a textbox matches any of the first values of each line in a textfile.

```
Dim sList As New List(Of String)(IO.File.ReadAllLines("Path"))
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To sList.Count - 1
        If sList(i).StartsWith(textbox1.Text) Then
            Label1.Visible = True
            Exit For
        Else
            Label1.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
```

The problem is if the textbox has 1 and the textfile has 11 it will display the label, what would be the best way around this?

I have tried sList(i).Contains etc but none of them are doing the job.

I have tried all the suggestions here and nothing works, my textfile has numbers like the following

```
11
15
18
```

and for example if i have the number 1 in the textbox then the label is visible.

Comment: What should come after the "1"?  What's the delimiter between the fields on each line?  Is there a space after the number?  Is there a tab?

Comment: tim i wouldnt expect the label to appear unless the textbox had "11", "15" or "18" not "1", Steve there is no tab or delimiter its just a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Label1.Visible = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Path.txt").Any(Function(f) f = TextBox1.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think LINQ can be used here:

```
Dim text = textbox1.Text
Dim textWithSpace = String.Format("{0} ", text)

Label1.Visible = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Path").Any(Function(line) line.StartsWith(textWithSpace) OrElse line = text)
```

You need import `System.Linq` to make it work.

I assumed that space ends each word in the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Label to be visible when at least one of the lines starts with the text in the `TextBox`, you can use LINQ and [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
Dim matchingLines = From l In IO.File.ReadLines("Path")
                    Where l.StartsWith(textbox1.Text)
Label1.Visible = matchingLines.Any()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following line, assuming you are reading from a text file and looking for an exact match of the whole line you could try this:

```
If sList(i).StartsWith(textbox1.Text + Environment.NewLine) Then
```

That should check to make sure its the only thing on that line as it is now looking for a new line and will not match '11'